# Synchronising Sqlite database between iPhone and Server

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4

Hi I am developing an app using local sqlite database.For example I want to change the database(sample.sqlite) in the iPhone by replacing another sqlite database file with same name from server with some url like "www.mymail.com/Sample.sqlite".Any thoughts please.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/cas.html)

Comment: I know that synchronization is possible but till now i never tried it. First time to know about the synchronization.Whether it is by using xml format or .sqlite format like in which format the conversion is possible.I want to know about the synchronization.Any tutorials please  or else any preferred sites.

Comment: Did you find down the solution?, any samples please

Comment: I didn't find suitable solutions anywhere.But according to my knowledge we can do that.Justby calling webservice we can download the sqlite file from server and at the same time we need to delete the old file in main bundle and also in documents.

Comment: I tried by calling the web service with local file.I put the local file path in webservice and tried it. It is working  fine.